# How to fix mysql subquery display

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT User.username,
       IFNULL(SUM(credit) - SUM(debit), 0) AS total,
       ( SELECT SUM(Bid.credit) - SUM(Bid.debit) AS freebids
           FROM users AS User
           LEFT
           JOIN bids AS Bid
             ON Bid.user_id = User.id
          WHERE Bid.type = 2
       ) AS FreeBids,
       ( SELECT SUM(Bid.credit) - SUM(Bid.debit) AS Normalbids
           FROM users AS User
           LEFT
           JOIN bids AS Bid
             ON Bid.user_id = User.id
          WHERE Bid.type = 0
             OR Bid.type = 1
       ) AS NormalBids
  FROM users AS User
  LEFT
  JOIN bids AS Bid
    ON Bid.user_id = User.id
 GROUP
    BY User.id
```

here is my sample table:
for users

```
id username 
1  user1
2  user2
3  user3
4  user4
```

For bids

```
id user_id debit credit type
1  1       0     10     0
2  1       1     5      2 
3  1       1     0      2
4  3       0     10     0
6  2       0     10     0
7  4       1     10     0
8  4       1     0      1
```

But I am having problem in displaying the subquery (Freebids and Normalbids) are all has the same value here are the sample display:

```
username    total   FreeBids    NormalBids
user1       10       12809          965
user2       20       12809          965
user3       9        12809          965
user4       0        12809          965
```

I can't figure out where did I go worng in my query.
Any suggestion to solve my problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The example is fairly good, but it can be improved by providing [sample table data](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html) as SQL `INSERT` statements, rather than table dumps. Desired results don't need to be SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why all the same values showed up was because there was no distinction between the `users` table in the outer query and the `users` table in the inner query. They both have the same alias. You must distinguish either the outer `users` table or the inner `users` table by assigning it with a different alias (such as `u`) so that the subquery knows which table to reference for the outer value:

```
... FROM users AS u ...
```

Having said that, it is highly inefficient to use subqueries like that as they would need to be executed for ***each*** row in your `users` table (we're talking about entire tables needing to be joined and filtered as many times as there are users x2).

Your query could be rewritten MUCH more efficiently using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    a.username,
    IFNULL(SUM(b.credit) - SUM(b.debit), 0) AS total,
    SUM(IF(b.type = 2, b.credit, 0)) - SUM(IF(b.type = 2, b.debit, 0)) AS freebids,
    SUM(IF(b.type IN (0,1), b.credit, 0)) - SUM(IF(b.type IN (0,1), b.debit, 0)) AS normalbids
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN bids b ON a.id = b.user_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.username
```

Which basically says: *SUM the credit/debit ONLY if the type is `x` value*, and you can SUM/COUNT/AVG/etc. on any condition you want just working with one table join.

---

### [SQL-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e606/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

Your combination of subqueries and joins doesn't really make sense: for each row of the outer query, each subquery will return the same set of many rows, rather than returning the correct single value that corresponds to the row of the outer query.

There are a few ways to do what you want, but I think the simplest is to eliminate the joins entirely, and use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT User.username,
       ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(credit) - SUM(debit), 0)
           FROM bids AS Bid
          WHERE Bid.user_id = User.id
       ) AS total,
       ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(credit) - SUM(debit), 0)
           FROM bids AS Bid
          WHERE Bid.user_id = User.id
            AND Bid.type = 2
       ) AS FreeBids,
       ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(credit) - SUM(debit), 0)
           FROM bids AS Bid
          WHERE Bid.user_id = User.id
            AND Bid.type IN (0, 1)
       ) AS NormalBids
  FROM users AS User
;
```

Each subquery refers to the `User` record from the outer query, keeping everything nicely organized.